# C# declaration of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, .net-4.0, types

Is it possible to get the "c# name" of a type obtained with reflexion like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

I would like to get:

```
List<String>
```

Is it possible without splitting strings? For example, using Reflection.

Thanks!

Comment: Describe what do you want to achieve, and we'll try to suggest more simple and reliable solution

Comment: You can build it from Type that you get it via reflection, type has GetGenericArguements that can help you build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it without resorting to splitting, parsing or manipulating strings by using [`CodeDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) and [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx):

```
using CodeDom;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

// ...

Type yourType = typeof(List<string>);  // for example

using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
    var typeRef = new CodeTypeReference(yourType);
    Console.WriteLine(provider.GetTypeOutput(typeRef));
}
```

(You may need to do some additional string manipulation to remove the namespace prefix. For example, if you want the output to be `List<string>` rather than `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`.)

Comment: I have added the splitting of namespace. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Not directly, but you can examine the type itself to figure it out.

```
public static string TypeName(Type t) {
    if (!t.IsGenericType) return t.Name;

    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    ret.Append(t.Name).Append("<");

    bool first = true;
    foreach(var arg in t.GetGenericArguments()) {
        if (!first) ret.Append(", ");
        first = false;

        ret.Append(TypeName(arg));
    }

    ret.Append(">");
    return ret.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Lasse: Whoops! You are entirely correct that it should go outside the if block (though, I disagree that it belongs at the bottom). You are also correct that it could be done better with Linq, though I'm not sure how (what with the recursion and all).

Comment: I removed my comment since it became at least partially obsolete. As for the LINQ part, here's how the loop could be implemented: `ret.Append(string.Join(", ", t.GetGenericArguments().Select(t => TypeName(t)).ToArray()));`

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean replace the body of the function with LINQ. Well, feel free to post your own answer (I won't steal that for my own, since it's your work!)

Comment: Nah, I actually like your answer better :) Easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse a string like:

```
t`x[[a(,b,c,d)]]
```

where t is actual type; x - number of generic parameters; a,b,c,d,etc - generic aguments

Answer (score 0):

> ...without splitting strings?

AFAIK, **no**.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the type to find out if it is nested or not and if it is generic constructed or a primitive type. In particular I've realized that nested generic types lists its generic arguments at the end of the type name string. That is mentioned in documentation [Type.GetType Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have partially solved the task and my solution passes the following tests.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Tests()
        {

            Assert.AreEqual("int",typeof(int).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());
            Assert.AreEqual("int[]",typeof(int[]).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());
            Assert.AreEqual("int?", typeof(int?).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());

            Assert.AreEqual("UnitTypeFriendlyNamesExtensionsTest.Inner2<string,IDictionary<string,object>>.SubInner<int,List<byte[]>,object>", typeof(Inner2<string,IDictionary<string,object>>.SubInner<int,List<byte[]>,object>).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());

            Assert.ThrowsException<NotImplementedException>(()=> typeof(Inner2<string, IDictionary<string, object>>.SubInner<int, List<byte[]>, object>).DeclaringType.ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());

            var t = typeof(TestGenericReturnType<DateTime>);
            var m = t.GetMethod("GetService");
            var tt = m.ReturnType;

            Assert.AreEqual("DateTime",tt.ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());

            Assert.AreEqual("IDictionary<string,object>",typeof(IDictionary<string,object>).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());
            Assert.AreEqual("IList<int[]>",typeof(IList<int[]>).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());
            Assert.AreEqual("UnitTypeFriendlyNamesExtensionsTest.Astruc?",typeof(Astruc?).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());
            Assert.AreEqual("UnitTypeFriendlyNamesExtensionsTest.Inner", typeof(Inner).ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName());
        }
```

The extensions class handles nested and generic constructed types as well as primitive types.

```
public static class TypeFriendlyNamesExtensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> TypeToFriendlyName = new Dictionary<Type, string>
    {
        {typeof(string), "string"},
        {typeof(object), "object"},
        {typeof(bool), "bool"},
        {typeof(byte), "byte"},
        {typeof(char), "char"},
        {typeof(decimal), "decimal"},
        {typeof(double), "double"},
        {typeof(short), "short"},
        {typeof(int), "int"},
        {typeof(long), "long"},
        {typeof(sbyte), "sbyte"},
        {typeof(float), "float"},
        {typeof(ushort), "ushort"},
        {typeof(uint), "uint"},
        {typeof(ulong), "ulong"},
        {typeof(void), "void"}
    };

    public static string ToCSharpMethodReturnTypeName(this Type type)
    {
        var sb = new StringWriter();
        ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, type);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static void ToCSharpNameEntry2(TextWriter sb, Type type0)
    {
        var list = GetContainingTypeList(type0);
        var usedGenericArgumentCounter = 0;

        HandleNestedLevel(sb, list, 0, ref usedGenericArgumentCounter);
        foreach (var ix in Enumerable.Range(1, list.Count - 1))
        {
            sb.Write(".");
            HandleNestedLevel(sb, list, ix, ref usedGenericArgumentCounter);
        }
    }

    private static void HandleNestedLevel(TextWriter sb, IReadOnlyList<Type> list, int ix,
        ref int usedGenericArgumentCounter)
    {
        var type = list[ix];
        if (TypeToFriendlyName.TryGetValue(type, out string fname))
        {
            sb.Write(fname);
            return;
        }
        if (type.IsGenericParameter)
        {
            sb.Write(type.Name);
            return;
        }
        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, type.GetElementType());
            sb.Write("[]");
            return;
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var innermostType = list[list.Count - 1];
            var args = list[list.Count - 1].GenericTypeArguments;
            if (!type.IsConstructedGenericType)
            {
                if (innermostType.IsConstructedGenericType)
                {
                    var sname = GetSname(type);
                    sb.Write(sname);
                    sb.Write("<");
                    ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, args[usedGenericArgumentCounter++]);
                    var loopCounter = ((TypeInfo) type).GenericTypeParameters.Length;
                    while (0 < --loopCounter)
                    {
                        sb.Write(",");
                        ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, args[usedGenericArgumentCounter++]);
                    }
                    sb.Write(">");
                    return;
                }
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            if (typeof(Nullable<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            {
                ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, args[0]);
                sb.Write("?");
                return;
            }
            var cname = GetSname(type);
            sb.Write(cname);
            sb.Write("<");
            ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, args[usedGenericArgumentCounter++]);
            while (usedGenericArgumentCounter < args.Length)
            {
                sb.Write(",");
                ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, args[usedGenericArgumentCounter++]);
            }
            sb.Write(">");
            return;
        }
        if (type.IsPointer)
        {
            ToCSharpNameEntry2(sb, type);
            sb.Write("*");
            return;
        }
        sb.Write(type.Name);
    }

    private static string GetSname(Type type)
    {
        var name = type.Name;
        return name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('`'));
    }

    private static List<Type> GetContainingTypeList(Type type)
    {
        var list = new List<Type> {type};
        var t = type;
        while (t.IsNested)
        {
            t = t.DeclaringType;
            list.Insert(0, t);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void ToCSharpNameEntry(StringBuilder sb, Type type)
    {
        var genericTypeArguments = type.GenericTypeArguments;
        var usedGenericTypeCounter = 0;
        ToCSharpNameRecursive(sb, type, genericTypeArguments, ref usedGenericTypeCounter);
    }

    private static void ToCSharpNameRecursive(StringBuilder sb, Type type, IReadOnlyList<Type> genericTypeArguments,
        ref int genericTypesCounter)
    {
        if (TypeToFriendlyName.TryGetValue(type, out string res))
        {
            sb.Append(res);
            return;
        }

        HandleNonPriminiveTypes(sb, type, genericTypeArguments, ref genericTypesCounter);
    }

    private static void HandleNonPriminiveTypes(StringBuilder sb, Type type, IReadOnlyList<Type> typeGenericTypeArguments,
        ref int genericTypesCounter)
    {
        var list = new List<Type>();
        var t = type;
        list.Add(t);
        while (t.IsNested)
        {
            t = t.DeclaringType;
            list.Add(t);
        }
        list.Reverse();
        foreach (var type1 in list)
        {
            HandleNestedLevel(sb, type1, typeGenericTypeArguments, ref genericTypesCounter);
            sb.Append(".");
        }
        sb.Length -= 1;
    }

    private static void HandleNestedLevel(StringBuilder sb, Type type, IReadOnlyList<Type> typeGenericTypeArguments,
        ref int genericTypesCounter)
    {
        var name = type.Name;
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            var info = type.GetTypeInfo();
            var def = info.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            var psLength = info.IsConstructedGenericType
                ? info.GenericTypeArguments.Length
                : info.GenericTypeParameters.Length;
            if (typeof(Nullable<>) == def)
            {
                var type1 = typeGenericTypeArguments[genericTypesCounter++];
                ToCSharpNameEntry(sb, type1);
                sb.Append("?");
                return;
            }

            var n = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("`", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            sb.Append(n);
            sb.Append("<");
            for (var i = 0; i < psLength; i++)
            {
                ToCSharpNameEntry(sb, typeGenericTypeArguments[genericTypesCounter++]);
                sb.Append(",");
            }
            sb.Length -= 1;
            sb.Append(">");
            return;
        }
        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            var type1 = type.GetElementType();
            ToCSharpNameEntry(sb, type1);
            sb.Append("[]");
            return;
        }
        sb.Append(name);
    }
}
```

I use the extension method while composing the source text to be compiled by Roslyn